# Checkbox не сохраняет состояние

Tags: java, android, checkbox

Дело в том, когда я чекаю `CheckBox`, то `ID` этого пункта сохраняется в `SQLite`. Их может быть много. Так вот когда обратно запускаю приложение, то там уже только последний выбранный `Checkbox` выделен, а остальные будто False;

В адаптере так:

```
public class MainVacancyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<VacancyModel> {

    private List<VacancyModel> vacancyModelList;
    private List<Integer> favVacanciesIDList;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    SQLHelper sqlHelper;

    public MainVacancyAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<VacancyModel> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        vacancyModelList = objects;
        this.resource = resource;
        sqlHelper = new SQLHelper(getContext());
        favVacanciesIDList = sqlHelper.getFavVacanciesID();
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);

            holder.tvHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeader);
            holder.tvDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPostCr);
            holder.cbxFav = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbxFav);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

        VacancyModel model = vacancyModelList.get(position);

        holder.tvHeader.setText(model.getHeader());
        holder.tvDate.setText(model.getDate());

        if (favVacanciesIDList != null){
            for (int i = 0; i < favVacanciesIDList.size(); i++){
                if (favVacanciesIDList.get(i) == vacancyModelList.get(position).getId()){
                    holder.cbxFav.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    holder.cbxFav.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        }

        holder.cbxFav.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int rowID = vacancyModelList.get(position).getId();
                if (isChecked) {
                    //inserting the data into Favourite Table
//                    isSelected.set(position, true);
                    vacancyModelList.get(position).setChecked(true);
                    sqlHelper.createFavouriteTable(vacancyModelList.get(position));
                } else {
                    vacancyModelList.get(position).setChecked(false);
                    sqlHelper.deleteFromFavouriteDatabase(rowID);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView tvHeader;
        private TextView tvDate;
        private CheckBox cbxFav;
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<CheckBox
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:id="@+id/cbxFav"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
            android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox_transparent"
            android:focusable="false"/>
```

Вот здесь

```
if (favVacanciesIDList != null){
            for (int i = 0; i < favVacanciesIDList.size(); i++){
                if (favVacanciesIDList.get(i) == vacancyModelList.get(position).getId()){
                    holder.cbxFav.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    holder.cbxFav.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        }
```

Все правильно и сравнил если равны то `сет`ится. Отладку делал.

Вопрос: **В чем может быть проблема?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас не правильная логика в определении ЧЕКнутости чекбокса, попробую объяснить. Допустим, в `favVacanciesIDList.get(3)` у вас содержится число, совпадающее с `vacancyModelList.get(position).getId()`, но всего в `favVacanciesIDList` 10 элементов.
Ваш цикл:

```
for (int i = 0; i < favVacanciesIDList.size(); i++){
    if (favVacanciesIDList.get(i) == vacancyModelList.get(position).getId()){
        holder.cbxFav.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        holder.cbxFav.setChecked(false);
    }
}
```

на четвертой итерации ваше условие `if` станет `true`, и выполнится `holder.cbxFav.setChecked(true);`. Дальше пойдет пятая итерация, и выполнится `holder.cbxFav.setChecked(false);`, что сделает чекбокс не чекнутым.

Как надо:

```
holder.cbxFav.setChecked(false); //поумолчанию снимаем галочку
for (int i = 0; i < favVacanciesIDList.size(); i++){
    if (favVacanciesIDList.get(i) == vacancyModelList.get(position).getId()){
        holder.cbxFav.setChecked(true); // если условие выполняется, то ставим галочку
        break;  // и заканчиваем цикл.
    } 
}
```

UPD

---

Можно сделать еще правильнее - хранить ЧЕКнутые элементы в `Set`, Например `HashSet<Integer>`. 
И целый цикл заменить на одну строчку:

```
holder.cbxFav.setChecked(favVacanciesIDSet.contains(vacancyModelList.get(position).getId()));
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!!! Все я понял)

Comment: @TITAN, обновил ответ. Можно сделать еще лучше

Comment: Вы знаете, я с этим возился 3 недели, короче, иду бухать)) Спасибо еще раз!!!

Comment: @TITAN, не за что, хорошего отдыха!